# index show content of an other file in httpd

Tags: configuration, web-config, apache

How can I configure http.conf to do this:

When I request to localhost/myfolder/index.html It will show content of /myfolder/myfile.html

Tks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apache, you could use an [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive, e.g.:

```
Alias /myfolder/index.html /somewhere/myfolder/myfile.html
```

Or you could use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html), e.g.:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/myfolder/index\.html$ /myfolder/myfile.html
```